# Load textdomain from global languages directory [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

I am creating translations for my plugin.
To fetch **.mo** files from my-plugin/languages directory , I use the function

```
//Load translation
function load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

How can i set the location to **wp-content/languages** 
Setting the location to `ABSPATH.'/wp-content/languages'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else is looking for the anwser , Here it is

```
function load_txtdomain() {
    $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', determine_locale(), 'my-plugin' );
    load_textdomain( 'my-plugin', WP_LANG_DIR . '/my-plugin-' . $locale . '.mo' );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','load_txtdomain');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware you've accepted your own answer, but although it will work it's against WordPress standards.

The `load_plugin_textdomain` will load from the global languages directory without modification and should be used for bootstrapping plugin translations. The path you specify as the third argument is a **fallback** to be used in case the global language file is not installed.

To clarify how it works: WordPress will look in the global languages directory strictly at `<WP_LANG_DIR>/plugins/my-plugin-<locale>.mo`. So as long your text domain and locale code are correct, it will be loaded.

If it isn't found, WordPress will look at the path you've specified which must be **relative** to the `wp-content/plugins` directory.

Historically (prior to WP 4.6) the third argument was loaded first, but WordPress decided to swap the order, favouring community translations (globally installed) over author-provided translations (shipped with plugin ).